# Why does out123_open () shut down my sound card?

Tags: alsa

I'm talking about this function call:

```
r = out123_open (sound::mp3_output_handle, "alsa", NULL);
```

The return value of `r` is then `OUT123_OK`, but in the same moment, the status LED on my sound card (JustBoom DAC HAT) is switched off, and the card delivers no sounds any more (until I reboot my Pi, at least). The debug messages emitted when `out123_open ()` is called look quite strange:

```
[src/libout123/modules/alsa.c:173] debug: open_alsa with (nil)
[src/libout123/modules/alsa.c:270] debug: close_alsa with 0x301918
Chosen output module: alsa
```

Apparently, when calling `init_alsa ()`, the function `close_alsa ()` is also called and switches off the sound card.

How can this be? Does everybody know hot to prevent ALSA from shutting down the sound card? Thank you.

UPDATE: Upon another user's advice, I found this when calling `dmesg`:

```
[  510.964076] pcm512x 1-004d: No SCLK, using BCLK: -2
[  510.970312] pcm512x 1-004d: Failed to request power down: -5
```

When calling mpg123 from the command line, though, I do get line 1, but not line 2, and the line with `close_alsa` is also missing in the debug output!

Comment: Do you have any messages about it on dmesg? **sudo dmesg** Maybe on /var/log/syslog?

Comment: Sure! See the update to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found the source of trouble: the I²C pins of the Raspi! In fact, the JustBoom card does work without I²C control, but I used the I²C pins as GPIO pins for another app, and the sound card thought I was issuing I²C commands, which, of course, were invalid. This is why using the mpg123 command-line app and even the example program at https://www.mpg123.de/api/mpg123__to__out123_8c.shtml did work flawlessly, whereas my app did not.